# How to create parametrized view in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two views like below

```
create view penord1_view 
as
    select 
        ser, docno, pcode, barcode, pname, unid, unit, qty, rate 
    from 
        sale 
    where    
        tc = 'O01' and docdt > @xdate1 and docdt < @xdate2

    union 

    select 
        sser as ser, sdocno as docno, pcode, barcode, pname, unid, unit, qty, rate 
    from     
        sale 
    where 
        tc = 'P01' and docdt > @xdate1 and docdt < @xdate2
```

and the second one is

```
create view penord_view 
as
    select 
        ser, docno, pcode, barcode, pname, unid, unit, rate, 
        SUM(qty) AS qty 
    from 
        penord1_view 
    group by 
        ser, docno, pcode, barcode, pname, unid, unit, rate
```

The problem is that I cannot pass `@xdate1` parameter in the first view.

Please suggest how to do this in a view or in some other way in SQL Server

Comment: Why pass any parameters? You could return the `docdt` field from the first view and add  `WHERE` statement in the second view

Comment: docdt cannot be returned from the first view because i  cannot sum using docdt

Comment: even i cannot use  function in view ....can i use a scaler function in view ?

Comment: You *can* use a table-valued function in a view, that's their main usage. What did you try? And why do you want parameters in the first place? Just expose `docdt`, filter by it and then *don't* include it in `GROUP BY` or SUM

Answer (score 1):

A view has no parameters by definition. You can see it as a saved query. If you would like to use parameters you should look into using stored procedures.

Comment: Functions, not stored procedures. Functions *can* be used in queries while stored procedures can't

Comment: you may also use a table valued function which will look like a paramete view.